# Is there a basis of a space $\mathbb{C}^3$ which has its linear map matrix diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let assume linear map $L: \mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$, defined as $Lu:=\langle v,u\rangle v$

where $u\in \mathbb{C}^3$ and $v\in \mathbb{C}^3$ is non-zero chosen vector with its norm $||v|| = 1$. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ stands for standard scalar multiplication on $\mathbb{C}^3$: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \bar v_1 u_1$.

**Is there a basis of a space $\mathbb{C}^3$ which has its matrix of linear map diagonal?**

---

The matrix of a linear map on a basis A is defined as:

$L = (La_1, La_2, La_3)$ where $A = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ is a basis.

---

I substituted the basis to the linear map and I got:

$$ L = 
\left(
\begin{array}
{ccc}
\bar v_1a_{11}v_1 + \bar v_2a_{12}v_1 + \bar v_3a_{13}v_1 & \bar v_1a_{11}v_2 + \bar v_2a_{12}v_2 + \bar v_3a_{13}v_2 & . \\
\bar v_1a_{21}v_1 + \bar v_2a_{22}v_1 + \bar v_3a_{23}v_1 & . & . \\
\bar v_1a_{31}v_1 + \bar v_2a_{32}v_1 + \bar v_3a_{33}v_1 & . & .
\end{array}\right)
$$

From which I can tell:

$
\bar v_1a_{11}v_2 + \bar v_2a_{12}v_2 + \bar v_3a_{13}v_2 = 0 \\
\bar v_1a_{21}v_1 + \bar v_2a_{22}v_1 + \bar v_3a_{23}v_1 = 0 \\
\bar v_1a_{31}v_1 + \bar v_2a_{32}v_1 + \bar v_3a_{33}v_1 = 0 \\
\vdots
$

However at this moment I am stumped. I can't get anything from those equations. I think the best way would be to show that $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are not linearly independent, hence $A$ can't be basis. Or maybe my method is all wrong?

Comment: Since $v \neq 0$, there is an orthonormal basis $\{v,v_1,v_2\}$ that contains $v$. What is the matrix of $L$ with respect to this basis?

Comment: Well, I guess: $$ L = 
\left(
\begin{array}
{ccc}
\langle v,v\rangle v \\
\langle v,v_1\rangle v \\
\langle v,v_2\rangle v
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}
{ccc}
v \\
\langle v,v_1\rangle v \\
\langle v,v_2\rangle v
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I feel problem here, I don't know what the $v$ looks like. If it's $(1,2,3)$ it already fails?

Comment: In such case, L is diagonal only if the first row is equal to $(1,0,0)$. That means $v=(1,0,0)$. The second row is equal to $\langle v,v_1 \rangle (1,0,0) = \bar v_1v$. So $L_{11} = 1, L_{12} = 0, L_{13} = 0$, but $L_{21} = \bar v_1v$ which is never equal to 0, because neither $\bar v_1$ nor $v_1$ is. Seems to me like a dead end. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** With respect to the standard basis, we have
$$
Lu = \langle v,u \rangle v = (v^*u)v = v(v^*u) = (vv^*)u
$$
That is, $L$ is represented by the matrix $vv^*$.  Note that this matrix is Hermitian.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the $v^*$ stands for? Or is that simply the scalar multiplication?

Comment: $v^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $v$.

Comment: I have to admit I'm lost at the first '=' already.

$\langle v,u\rangle = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \bar v_1 u_1$ = $\bar v_1u_1 + \bar v_2u_2 + \bar v_3u_3$

How do you get to $v^*$?

Comment: Go through the matrix multiplication

Comment: I'm sorry, but what matrix? You mean multiply all that with $v$? I've done that in the question

Comment: I finally understand. At the end we have $Lu=u$. I am going to investigate this further.

Comment: Hm, does that mean that the L matrix is diagonal for basis $ \{ (x,0,0), (0,y,0), (0,0,z)|x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z} \} $?